# while uploading file in postman that file is not stored in destination folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

```
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const db = require('./db');
const Image = db.images;
const fileUploadModel = require('./../upload-model');
const path = require('path');

var upload = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req.files.file.name);
    var uploadDoc = req.files.file;
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({

        destination: function (req,files, cb) {
          cb(null, './temp')
        },
        filename: function (req,files, cb) {
            var datetimestamp = Date.now();
            cb(null, uploadDoc.originalname.split('.')[uploadDoc.originalname.split('.').length - 2] + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + uploadDoc.originalname.split('.')[uploadDoc.originalname.split('.').length - 1]);

        }
      })

      var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
    var fileUpload = new fileUploadModel(req.files.file);
    fileUpload.save({
            type:uploadDoc.type,
            name:uploadDoc.name,
            data: fs.readFileSync('./temp/'+uploadDoc.name)
        }).then(image => {
            try{
                fs.writeFileSync('./temp-uploads/' + image.name, image.data);       

                res.json({'msg': 'File uploaded successfully!', 'file': uploadDoc.file});


            }catch(e){
                console.log(e);
                res.json({'err': e});
            }
        })


};
```

In temp folder nothing is stored .where i read the file that time shows Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory.

In this data: `fs.readFileSync('./temp/'+uploadDoc.name)` line only getting error because in temp folder files are not store.I dont know where i did mistake.

First it's causing problem req.file is umdefined after that i resolve.
Now it's causing error in destination folder.

Comment: did you set in postman in body of request - type: file

Comment: Also, what do you get here: console.log(req.files)

Comment: It could be that in  var fileUpload = new fileUploadModel(req.body); as argument you are passing req.body, but later you are using req.files.type.

Comment: Also, maybe this could be helpful https://medium.com/@bmshamsnahid/nodejs-file-upload-using-multer-3a904516f6d2

Comment: i am using console.log(req.files.file.name) getting pdf file name

Comment: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\webservices\task\upload-document\uploads\410349120.pdf'

Comment: in this line getting error data: fs.readFileSync('./uploads/' + req.files.file.name) and throw error like no such directory

Comment: someone help please

Comment: uploaded file is not stored in destination folder.help me please i can't able to resolve last 2 days

Comment: I want to try. Could you please make codesandbox or git repository with all your files since it could be that the error is somewhere else and not in the code you have shown here. You are using fileUploadModel which is not shown here.

Comment: finally i uninstall after that i created new one